# WSO2 Governance: configure different versions of service in WSO2 Application server?

Tags: service, version, wso2

We have a wso2 1.6.0 installation of an application server, esb etc (components themselves are of differing versions). I just started WSO2 Governance (v 4.5.3). My goal is to configure different versions of our existing services in the app server and serve them according to the user who is making the request. Is there a tutorial on this anywhere? Can you tell me the steps?

I saw within the governance manager web interface there is a form to configure services versions, but I am in doubt as to how I identify that service as being the same as my application app service, and how do I configure usage of service versions based on requesting user. Any help highly appreciated. Thanks!